# How do you unban a meid on an iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers, cellular-data, meid

Does anyone know to unlock a meid on an iPhone 4 for Alltel? I bought an iPhone, which turned out to be blacklisted. All the tutorials I see on YouTube shows every carrier except Alltel.

Answer (score 5):

Blacklisted IMEI or MEID on iPhones are usually one of two things:

1. Clerical mistakes - contact the police or a cell carrier for assistance in clearing up that mistake.
2. Stolen goods (or goods reported as stolen) - again the police or a lawyer might be your next step if you find out you have purchased stolen goods.

You might want to contact the seller and/or eBay to get your money back or dispute the sale (assuming the seller didn't disclose that the phone was locked and/or blacklisted in the terms of the sale). I wouldn't recommend anyone alter their MEID/IMEI until they were well aware of local laws with respect to carrier billing and at least understood that potentially fraudulent activities are possible. Perhaps even putting you at risk by simply altering these identification numbers even if you don't intend anything other than to use the phone with a carrier that welcomes that device on their network.